# Will Epoll work with UDP listening socket for having a event driven UDP server

Tags: c, sockets, udp, dtls

I am trying to create a event driven multiple threads UDP/DTLS server. The design is based on the following concepts

1. Have a UDP socket where the Clients connects on
2. Use Epoll to ask for events on the UDP listen socket.
3. The UDP socket acts as a TCP listen socket and creates child fds that connect to the specific client. For this I have implemented a UDPAccept method for my object which has the pseudo code as shown below

   ```
   UDPAccept(int fd,struct sockaddr * addr,
      socklen_t * addr_len,void *sockBuf,size_t *read)
   {
       //sanity checks
       int childfd = -1;
       int error = 1;
       socklen_t localLen,peerLen;
       int family;
       struct sockaddr_in         local4,peer4;
       struct sockaddr            temp;
       size_t maxLen = 65535;
       getsockname(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&temp,&localLen);
       family = temp.sa_family;
       do
       {
        childfd = socket(family,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
        //error handling       
        //handle IPV6 
        local4 = (sockaddr_in *)temp;
        error = recvfrom( fd, sockBuf,
                           maxLen,0,(struct sockaddr *)&peer4,
                                            &peerLen);
        error = bind(childfd,(struct sockaddr *)&local4,sizeof local4);
        error = connect(childfd,(struct sockaddr *)&peerV4,peerLen);
       //handle error      
      }while(0);
      if(addr != NULL && addr_len != NULL)
      {
       *addr_len = peerLen;
       addr = &peerV4;
       *read = error;
      }    
      // error handling and cleanup
      return childfd;
   }
   ```
4. Add the child socket to Epoll table.

   ```
   epoll_ctl(efd,EPOLL_CTL_ADD,newFd,&event);
   ```
5. Poll for events on the child and listen socket

   ```
   currentSize = epoll_wait(efd,events,MAX_SOCKET_FD,timeout);
   //handle errors
   for(i = 0; i < currentSize;i++)
   {

       if(events[i].data.fd == listenUDP)
           //call UDPAccept
           // update local tables
      else
           //handle child fd events
   }
   ```
6. Have multiple threads to the same thing, synchronize using locks during accept

Now my question is will epoll stop giving me POLLIN events on the listening socket because I have created a new UDP child connected socket to the client or will I have to handle it myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will deliver events on both sockets unless you remove the first socket from `events`.

But I'm wondering why you're doing this. You can use a single UDP socket for everything. It's much simpler.

Comment: Agreed it would be much simpler, but we are trying to build a mini DTLS server which should potentially handle 100,000 simultaneous clients sending data at line rate, I may be wrong but,using a single socket would end up being the bottleneck.
I am not sure what other design approach should I follow.

Comment: The server would be sitting on a 40 Gbps line. I don't think network would be a problem, on the other hand,again no benchmarks available yet just a hypothesis, but if we have a single socket we would not be able to handle it without having significant drop of data packets as it would be single core processing a single socket at a time

Comment: I believe you can have the same UDP socket used from multiple threads and get reasonable results (although it would be non-deterministic which thread gets which incoming UDP packet).  I'd probably do a socket-per-thread just on general principles, though.  Note that in either case, it's the presence of multiple threads that is making the difference, not the presence of multiple sockets.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner agreed that the presence of multiple threads makes the difference but consider this scenario.
If I have a single socket and even if I have 4 threads reading from that socket I may need a way to synchronize who reads when because they all cannot read at the same time from the socket queue, but if I have multiple child connected sockets they will have data in the queue only from their respective queue hence making ti independent to run on different threads simultaneously isn`t it ?

Comment: @cmidi my understanding is that under most OS's you are not required to synchronize recv()s from a socket.  (of course that may just mean that the OS is implicitly synchronizing the reads on your behalf, in which case the same bottleneck might be present inside the recv() call; OTOH the OS might be using some clever lockless technique to avoid that.  And in any case, the OS will still have to deliver bytes from a single network-driver to their destination socket-buffers, so it seems to me that unless the OS implementers have gone lockless, there would be a synchronization step there anyway)

Comment: @cmidi `recv()` is a system call, and all system calls are atomic. Your fears are unfounded.

Comment: @EJP you are absolutely right, the whole design for having a UDP accept was based on creating DTLS
 `SSL object` associations based on socket fd, as `SSL_read` `SSL_write` calls on same socket are not thread safe.
Based on your suggestions I was actually able to design a state machine where my UDP listening socket is creating work for my multiple epoll threads by adding child sockets to their tables. I had to have dedicated UDP listen socket thread because, as you suggested in your answer, I was getting epoll events on the listening socket for all the child sockets data too.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Linux man page on connect(), a filter will ensure only datagrams from the "connected" peer will be delivered to the new socket.

One caveat though...  The bind() call will briefly take over the port from the listener until the connect call().  It's a small window, but can result in datagrams from other clients appearing on the "connected" socket.  You can ignore them by validating the peer address.